# How do I parse this JSON with Aeson?

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I have the following JSON snippet:

```
{
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 803,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "broken clouds",
      "icon": "04n"
    }
  ],
  "main": {
    "temp": 271.979,
    "pressure": 1024.8,
    "humidity": 100,
    "temp_min": 271.979,
    "temp_max": 271.979,
    "sea_level": 1028.51,
    "grnd_level": 1024.8
  },
  "id": 6332485,
  "name": "Queensbridge Houses",
  "cod": 200
}
```

I want to get parse the following type from it:

```
data WeatherResponse = WeatherResponse
  { temp :: Double
  , humidity :: Double
  , weatherMain :: T.Text
  } deriving Show
```

I've been trying to use the following code to do it, but I keep running into errors. I've finally got all the types to match up, but it parses incorrectly and don't really understand where it's failing.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser, Array)
import Data.Time (defaultTimeLocale, formatTime, getZonedTime)

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Text as T

data WeatherResponse = WeatherResponse
  { temp :: Double
  , humidity :: Double
  , weatherMain :: T.Text
  } deriving Show

lambda3 :: Value -> Parser T.Text
lambda3 o = do
  withText "main" (\t -> do
                      return t
                  ) o

parseInner :: Value -> Parser T.Text
parseInner a = withArray "Inner Array" (lambda3 . (V.head)) a

instance FromJSON WeatherResponse where
  parseJSON =
    withObject "Root Object" $ \o -> do
    mainO <- o .: "main"
    temp <- mainO .: "temp"
    humidity <- mainO .: "humidity"
    weatherO <- o .: "weather"
    weatherMain <- parseInner weatherO
    return $ WeatherResponse temp humidity weatherMain

getSampleData = BL.readFile "/home/vmadiath/.xmonad/weather.json"

main = do
  text <- getSampleData
  let (result :: Either String WeatherResponse) = eitherDecode text
  putStrLn . show  $ result
```

I simply get the following output which doesn't give me enough to know where I've gone wrong.

```
$ runhaskell lib/code.hs
Left "Error in $: expected main, encountered Object"
```

I've put the entire thing in a gist viewable [here](https://gist.github.com/vamega/7c04b1ee22bad8eca7ba)

I'd like to know what's wrong with the code, and how I can fix it. If you have suggestions of how to write this in a more readable way I'd love to know that too. Currently I'm mostly annoyed with the  two separate functions `lambda3` and `parseInner` is annoying)

Comment: By `V.head` you got the first element in the `weather` array which is an object, so it should be `lambda3 = withObject "weatherMain" (.: "main")
`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you are making this too complicated. Something like this should work:

```
instance FromJSON WeatherResponse where
  parseJSON (Object v) = do
      weatherValue <- head <$> v .: "weather"
      WeatherResponse <$> ((v .: "main") >>= (.: "temp"))
                          <*> ((v .: "main") >>= (.: "humidity"))
                          <*> weatherValue .: "main"
```

It's output:

```
[nix-shell:~/haskell-sample]$ ./weather
Right (WeatherResponse {temp = 271.979, humidity = 100.0, weatherMain = "Clouds"})
```